# Jquery won't load

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I can't seem to get Jquery to work on my aspx file. I'm trying to display a simple progress bar at the moment :

```
    <head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <link href="css/Home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({
        value:false
    });
    </script>

    </head>

<body>
 <div id="progressbar"></div>
</body>
```

I've also tried to use the Jquery source and Microsoft CDN. ITs as simple as nothing happens. I have a `<div id="progressbar">` in the HTML which never turns out to be a progressbar like the Jquery UI one. I've tried to load a Jquery calendar aswell with the same result. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

I'm 100% sure i've non 404 error on the js or css files and I have no error in the debug console on IE or Chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
$(function() {    
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({
        value:false
    });  
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, I'll accept as soon as I can, I'm not familiar enough with jquery

Comment: @WizLiz check this explanation out http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 2):

Try to wrap your code inside DOM ready handler `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` or shorter form `$(function() { ... })` to make sure all the elements inside your DOM are loaded properly before executing your jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({
        value:false
    });  
});
```

Comment: Do I always have to wrap it that way ? I don't udnerstand how it works

Comment: If you put the script inside the head section then you need to wrap it. If you put your jQuery code at the end of your page before closing  `</body>` tag, then you don't need to do so.

Comment: Okay, is there anything which is preferred then ?

Comment: The second way is preferred since it makes your site load faster: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

Answer (score 1):

Your script works but does know know when to start. Try using:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({
        value:false
    });
});
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

put that in document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#progressbar").progressbar({
        value:false
    });  
});
```